# EasyAdmin: Error on change formTypeOptions property field in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, easyadmin

I've an **User** entity and EasyAdmin (EA) **UserCrudController** for manage to them.
The **User** entity has **active** boolean field. And I want that field will be disabled for current user in admin interface.
I got a working solution:

```
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/crud/index.html.twig' %}

{% block table_body %}
...
{% for field in entity.fields %}
                    
                    {# disable active field for current uset #}
                    {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
                        {% if app.user.id == entity.instance.id and field.property == 'active' %}
                            {% set templatePath = 'admin/crud/field/_boolean_disabled.html.twig' %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% set templatePath = field.templatePath %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <td data-label="{{ field.label|e('html_attr') }}" class="{{ field.property == sort_field_name ? 'sorted' }} text-{{ field.textAlign }} {{ field.cssClass }}" dir="{{ ea.i18n.textDirection }}">
                        {{ include(templatePath, { field: field, entity: entity }, with_context = false) }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
...
```

with override EA boolean template.

But I wouldn't want to override EA boolean template and only complete **field.formTypeOptions** by element **'disabled': 'true'**

```
{% for field in entity.fields %}
                    
                    {# disable active field for current uset #}
                    {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
                        {% if app.user.id == entity.instance.id and field.property == 'active' %}
                            {% set field.formTypeOptions = field.formTypeOptions|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <td data-label="{{ field.label|e('html_attr') }}" class="{{ field.property == sort_field_name ? 'sorted' }} text-{{ field.textAlign }} {{ field.cssClass }}" dir="{{ ea.i18n.textDirection }}">
                        {{ include(field.templatePath, { field: field, entity: entity }, with_context = false) }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
```

But for this path I get an error: "Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: "Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected)." at /home/vagrant/code/blog.local/templates/admin/crud/user/index.html.twig line 27"

line 27: {% set field.formTypeOptions = field.formTypeOptions|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}

When I do:

```
{% set x = field.formTypeOptions|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}
{{ dump(x) }}

array:7 [▼
  "required" => false
  "row_attr" => array:1 [▶]
  "attr" => array:1 [▶]
  "label" => "Active"
  "label_translation_parameters" => []
  "label_attr" => array:1 [▶]
  "disabled" => "true"
]
```

I get the required array, but I get the same error when I try to assign a new value

```
{% set field.formTypeOptions = field.formTypeOptions|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to let you know how pleased I am to see the correct handling of an abbreviation. Using the long form the first time and the abbreviation in brackets right behind it. And then using the abbreviation from there on. I wish everyone would do it like that. Kudos!

Comment: Hey @Quatsch can you elaborate? Maybe I am not doing it and I would like to learn

Comment: Hi @S.Dre, sure thing. The author of the question wrote "EasyAdmin (EA)" instead of just writing "EA", because not everyone might be that familiar with that abbreviation. So to prevent misunderstandings he uses the long term and writes the abbreviation for that in brackets right behind it. From there on he can safely use the abbreviation. I personally often stop reading the question of someone if he uses niche abbreviations that I have no idea of what they could mean.

Comment: Ohhh Ok, I thought you were saying in the code itself. But yeah, I really agree with what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the merge function does not like punctuations. Try to set the value to a variable before:

Change:

```
{% set field.formTypeOptions = field.formTypeOptions|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}
```

To:

```
   {% set options = field.formTypeOptions %}
   {% set field.formTypeOptions = options|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks Quatsch! I tested this way but got the same error on line: {% set field.formTypeOptions = options|merge({'disabled': 'true'}) %}

Answer (score 0):

You could already do that in UserCrudController and avoid that logic in Twig:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    // ...

    // check user/roles
    $isInputDisabled = true;
    if($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
        $isInputDisabled = false;
    }
    
    // ...
    
    $active = BooleanField::new('active', 'Active')
        ->setFormTypeOption('disabled', $isInputDisabled);

    // ...
}
```